# Affine manifolds References

Tags: affine-geometry

Does anyone know of any online pdf lectures on affine manifolds?  I'm interested in compact affine manifolds.  Specifically, I'm looking for specific examples of compact affine manifolds where the affine charts are specified.

Comment: Google the work of William Goldman. He has lecture notes on affine manifolds, among other things. All affine structures on the $2$-torus have been classified by Benzecri and Kuiper. See also [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/178252/affine-structures).

Comment: Just beat me to it Dietrich --- Bill and I were in college together, and he's been interested in these since the late 1970s!